# Best way to convert an ASCII digit to its numeric value

Tags: c++, c, performance, embedded, energy

Lets say I have an ASCII character representing a decimal digit:

```c
char digit;  // between 0x30 ('0') and 0x39 ('9') inclusive
```

I want to get the numeric value it represents (between `0` and `9`).
I am aware of two possible methods:

1. subtraction:

   ```c
   uint8_t value = digit - '0';
   ```
2. bitwise and:

   ```c
   uint8_t value = digit & 0x0f;
   ```

Which one is the most efficient in terms of compiled code size?
Execution time? Energy consumption? As the answer may be
platform-specific, I am most interested about the kind of architectures
one may find in microcontrollers running low-power applications:
Cortex-M, PIC, AVR, 8051, etc. My own [test on an Arduino Uno](https://gist.github.com/edgar-bonet/7afbf8b1df02534ac142cf84bb12e87a)
seems to indicate that on AVR it doesn't make much of a difference, but
I still would like to hear about other architectures.

Bonus questions: can either method be called “industry standard”? Are
there situations where choosing the right one is essential?

**Disclaimer**: this is a followup to [a discussion](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/77949/7508) on an
answer from arduino;stackexchange.com.

Comment: "Which one is the most efficient" - Neither. It doesn't matter one bit. In an optimized build you'll most likely get the same assembly. And even if you don't, microscopic optimizations like this are ever only going to save you nanoseconds - not anything you could ever notice, so don't worry about it.

Comment: If we're interested in saving energy, how about we never store the digit in ASCII format in the first place?

Comment: @JesperJuhl there is no possible way that the optimizer would produce the same instructions for those two snippets.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Even on an application powered by a single CR2025 battery?

Comment: `digit - '0'` is guaranteed to work on all platforms.  `digit & 0x0F` works on all platforms that I'm aware of, but is not guaranteed by the C or C++ standards that digit characters are represented in a BCD compatible kind of format for all character sets.

Comment: @Edgar I doubt it. But run some benchmarks if you really need to know.

Comment: @Eljay the question is about the ASCII. All other deliberations are off-topic

Comment: @P__J__ • *Bonus questions: can either method be called “industry standard”? Are there situations where choosing the right one is essential?*

Comment: @Eljay what does it mean "industry standard" - elaborate and give definition.

Comment: @P__J__ • You'll have to ask the OP.

Comment: Re “_industry standard_”: I am quoting this from another user. @tim: would you elaborate on what you mean by this?

Comment: Are you concerned about converting ONE digit? Or do you have a sequence of the in memory? Bitwise method would cleanly scale to processing 4 or even 8 digits at a time (not sure about your architecture).

Comment: @VladFeinstein: The end goal is to convert a 2-digit number.

Comment: If you are going so far as to say energy efficient, then you need to not use C or any other high level language (except to make a rough cut at the first draft of the code).   Cant possibly imagine this question cares about energy consumption (subtract which is an add takes more gates of course, flips more bits so will consume more).

Answer (score 1):

You should compile it yourself.

```
int foo(char x)
{
    return x - '0';
}

int foo1(char x)
{
    return x & 0x0f;
}

char foo2(char x)
{
    return x - '0';
}

char foo3(char x)
{
    return x & 0x0f;
}
```

and the code

```
__tmp_reg__ = 0
foo(char):
        mov __tmp_reg__,r24
        lsl r0
        sbc r25,r25
        sbiw r24,48
        ret
foo1(char):
        andi r24,lo8(15)
        ldi r25,0
        ret
foo2(char):
        subi r24,lo8(-(-48))
        ret
foo3(char):
        andi r24,lo8(15)
        ret
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say I want an 8-bit result (like `foo2()` and `foo3()`). I just edited the question.

Comment: @EdgarBonet so as you see they are identical

Comment: Almost identical. `subi` and `andi` are different instructions that involve different gates within the ALU. The number of transistors switching states can be different, and thus the energy consumption. A stackoverflow user is telling me that in low-power applications it is “essential” (his word) to choose the right one. Also, on other architectures the performance difference may be larger than on AVR.

Comment: @Edgar if you don't know which is more energy efficient, then I'd question the necessity of spending time finding out which is more efficient. But if there's an actual measurable difference between the two, and one is known to be more efficient, why wouldn't you use it?

Comment: @EdgarBonet they are identical they take 1 cycle.Your comment does not make any sense. BTW on 16 ot 32 bits systems use the `int` as it is more efficient,.

Comment: BTW interesting who has DV-ted me and why

Comment: @P__J__ we all agree that both instructions take 1 clock cycle. The difference is in energy consumption between the two instructions.

Comment: @JohnFilleau it does not make any difference as program energy consumption is much broader problem and program does not do only this one instruction. It is pre pre pre mature optimization which does not make any sense.

Comment: @P__J__ Then that's a fine answer. "Who cares?" is a fine answer. But to say to Edgar that their comment doesn't make sense doesn't itself make sense. The question of which is more energy efficient makes sense, whether you think the answer is worth anyone's time or not.

Comment: @JohnFilleau the energy efficiency is identical to the level which stop to make any practical significance. So the answer is: it does not matter for the program power consumption.

Comment: @P__J__ - I don't have enough rep to DV you, but I do have enough to UV you :)

Comment: Maybe a quick bench link would help here?

Comment: Cant imagine why the OP is asking for energy efficiency for a question like this.  subtract which is an adder circuit has more gates, more signals flipping for an operation like this and will consume more power than an and...on any architecture...(good luck trying to measure it)...That part of the question really needs to go away and leave it with and or subtract use either one if they take the same time, if subtract takes more clocks as it might with some architectures then use and, also assuming instruction sizes are the same.

Comment: for this architecture it is a wash, done, move on...

Comment: Wow, okay followed the link from the question.  Folks are really not grasping these concepts, this question is not where you save battery life.  Nor is binary size necessarily if you dont have to move to a larger part.   And what you do need to do to preserve battery consumption is not going to translate very well from an 8051 to avr to cortex-m based chip, etc.  or even from one cortex-m to another